React js web app. socket.io notification event not being triggered or the client not catching it
i have a MERN web app, when a user applies for an internship a notification gets sent to the enterprise, the pushNotification function is being triggered and the notification is getting saved, the socketId is there, everything looks fine but it wont work, i dont know if its either the client is not catching the event or its something else
index.js
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

// Create an HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Configure CORS for Socket.IO
const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// Socket.IO events
let users = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join', (userId) => {
    users[userId] = socket.id;
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    // remove the user from the users object
    users = Object.keys(users).reduce((result, key) => {
      if (users[key] !== socket.id) {
        result[key] = users[key];
      }
      return result;
    }, {});
  });
});

app.set('io', io);
app.set('users', users);

pushNotification function(server)
const pushNotification = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { senderId, recipientId, type, title, html } = req.body;
        const notification = new Notification({
            senderId,
            recipientId,
            type,
            title,
            html
        });
        await notification.save();

        // emit an event to the recipient
        const io = req.app.get('io');
        const users = req.app.get('users');
        console.log(users);
        const socketId = users[recipientId];
        console.log(socketId);
        if (socketId) {
            io.to(socketId).emit('notification', notification);
        }

        res.json(notification);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
};

NotificationPanel component
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { PiBellSimpleBold } from 'react-icons/pi'
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import axios from 'axios'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
import { useUser } from '../hooks/useUser'

const notificationUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/system/get-notifications'
const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');


function NotificationPanel() {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const { user } = useUser();

    const MAX_NOTIFICATIONS = 5;

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchNotifications = async () => {
            console.log('Fetching notifications');
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(notificationUrl);
                console.log(response);
                const filteredNotifications = response.data.filter(notification => notification.recipientId === user.id);
                setNotifications(filteredNotifications);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };

        socket.on('notification', fetchNotifications);

        // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
        return () => {
            socket.off('notification', fetchNotifications);
        };
    }, [user.id]);


    const variants = {
        open: { opacity: 1, y: 0 },
        closed: { opacity: 0, y: -10 },
    };

    return (
        <div className="relative">
            <div className="bg-[#F7FF9F] rounded-lg px-4 py-3.5 flex items-center cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
                <PiBellSimpleBold className='scale-125' />
            </div>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {isOpen && (
                    <motion.div
                        className="dropdown absolute top-12 right-0 bg-gray-100 p-3 rounded-lg w-96"
                        initial="closed"
                        animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
                        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -10 }}
                        variants={variants}
                        transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
                    >
                        <div className="dropdown-content space-y-2">
                            {notifications.length > 0 ? (
                                notifications.map((notification) => (
                                    <div key={notification._id}>
                                        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                                            <h1 className="font-semibold text-sm">Test</h1>
                                            <p className="text-xs">{notification.title}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            ) : (
                                <p className='font-inter'>No notifications</p>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </motion.div>
                )}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotificationPanel

i tried few solutions, joining the client to a room with the user id on join and now im trying adding the client that just joined to a user array with the socketId
